# Add dynamic li element and remove the respective one in VUEJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new in VUE JS.

I have a form where I want to add multiple media. 
So on click of "Add media" button i want to add "li" tag with respective html content in which i have on remove button too.

On click on remove button i want to delete the respective li.

What will be the best way to do this?

Here is what i have done so far

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                          <button @click="addMediaRow()" class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="mediaRowCount >= 3" type="button">Add Media</button>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;" id="project_media_ul">
                                <li v-for="(row, index) in mediaRowArr">
                                  <span v-html="row.template"></span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

JS

In data i have declared variable

```
mediaRowLI: '<a v-on:click="openMediaFileInput"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;\n' +
    '                                        <span class="photospan">Add Photo </span></a>\n' +
    '                                    or Input Video URL here : <input type="text" class="form-control"\n' +
    '                                                                     placeholder="use embed URL, e.g. www.youtube.com/embed/EXa9ZeqRKl8"\n' +
    '                                                                     name="media_video_url" style=" width: 50%">\n' +
    '                                    \n' +
    '                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-danger" v-on:click="removeMediaRow"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '                                    <input multiple type="file" accept=\'image/x-png,image/jpeg\' name="media_images"\n' +
    '                                           style="visibility: hidden;">\n' +
    ''
```

Methods :

```
addMediaRow () {
    this.mediaRowArr.push({
      template: this.mediaRowLI
    })
  },
  removeMediaRow (key) {
    this.mediaRowArr.splice(key, 1)
  },
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your code to the question and describe where exactly you are stuck. Currently, your question is too broad and too unspecific to be answered.

Comment: Search for todo apps in Vue. You need to create an array and loop through it to create the `li`. On click of add, `push` a new item. On remove, `splice` the item from the array

Comment: Please post the fiddle of what you have done so far

Comment: I have added the code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

> you cannot use `v-html` to compose template partials, because Vue is
> not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are
> preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition.
> ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML))

meaning html raw with `v-on:click="removeMediaRow"` doesn't work.

As the documentation says, you should create a component instead.
([jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/fu0yr7z5/5/))

Comment: Hi @Sovalina,  Thank you for your response. Here when i click on remove it remove the last element in the list, which should delete the respective row :(